# Spark streaming receives byte[] from Kafka

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I want integrate Apache Kafka and Spark Streaming, I am using spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11, I found this function showing below, but the type of value in Kafka is byte array. How can I get a byte array from Kafka using this function？

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.*;

JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream =
     KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(streamingContext,
         [key class], [value class], [key decoder class], [value decoder class],
         [map of Kafka parameters], [set of topics to consume]);
```

Comment: JavaPairInputDStream<String, byte[]>

Comment: Any reason you do not use Structured Streaming over DStream?

Comment: I have try JavaPairInputDStream<String, byte[]>, but what should param [value class] be? [value decoder class] can by DefaultDecoder.class